# Clear Flash Builder mobile application cache

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am building a Flex mobile application using Flash Builder 4.5, and testing it on a Samsung Galaxy 10.1 tab running Honeycomb.

I have integrated the AS3 Facebook library, but it won't let me log out, the session seems to stay behind, so once a user has logged in, they stay logged in until I have cleared the applications cache, or uninstalled and re-installed the application on the device.

What I would like to achieve here is to delete the cache folder for the application, or somehow clear the cache.

Any idea on how I can achieve this using AS3? Is there a better way of going about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following event listener to you main application file `applicationComplete` or `initialize` event handler:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, onDeactivateApp);
```

In onDeactivateApp function do the following:

```
protected function onDeactivateApp(event:Event):void
{

    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
}
```

This should clear the cache, and the application will make you log back in when you restart it. This should be added to most mobile applications by the way.

Brian

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Is there a way to clear the cache and not exit the application by any chance? Because I am looking to clear the cache while the application is still active, if at all possible.

Comment: I've given that a go and no luck. :/ The above seems to work, but every now and again it doesn't clear everything, because it still automatically logs me in after about the 3rd time I open the app. Any ideas?

Comment: There must still be some objects that are not being cleared. You could also have a popup appear before the deactive app finsihes that warns the user that they will be logged off. Then force the Facebook API to log out before continuing.

Comment: Link for the article on killing the APP: http://www.riagora.com/2010/12/tips-for-flex-mobile-apps/